# How to use Jasmine's toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining) method to compare arrays?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically I wanna check corresponding elements of the arrays I partially equal.

Is there anything better than `foreach loop` with a nested `toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining)`?

Comment: Can you please include more of your testing code to give additional context to the problem and the way you're trying to use `toEqual`?

Comment: @DacreDenny I had a huge number of test for some object (e.g., player) and now I dynamically added 1 field to it (e..g, name) and everything's failing because it didn't expect it to be there at all (I use equals(colllection1, collection2). So collection1 is kinda an input and collection2 is what I get as an output (collection<Player>), but I add one more field so they differ as a result.

Comment: I'd like to run .equals w/o that field and I believe objectContainting can help here (it does help for 1-2 objects), is there a nice idea how to wrap it into a collection?

Answer (score 0):

With angularjs and Jasmine 3.3.1, I have been successful with this kind of structure:

```
it('updates an prop on every object in an array', () => {
  const result = service.methodThatUpdates([{ prop: 'orig' }, { prop: 'orig' }]);
  expect(result).toEqual([
    jasmine.objectContaining({ prop: 'changed' }),
    jasmine.objectContaining({ prop: 'changed' })
  ]);
});
```

It is simpler than many `toEqual` calls.